# Remove Whitespace Before Committing Files to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, whitespace

Visual Studio gives us this great ability to completely customize our work environment, including how we wish to format whitespace.  I am very particular about how and where I want tabs, spaces, braces, etc. to appear.

For instance, I prefer tabs to be inserted as tabs not spaces.  I also prefer the indentation (Tab size/Indent size) to only be 2 spaces (frankly I don't need 4 spaces to see that the line has been indented).

This is all well and good until I work collaboratively.  Everyone else I work with just seem to use the defaults for whitespace/formatting.  This causes problems when using source control like TFS.  If you compare files worked on by me and then a co-worker, the changes in whitespace also show up.  I don't want to see these changes; they're not significant.

Please don't tell me the answer is that the entire team should use the same settings.  This isn't the correct answer.  That answer is a cop-out for bad design.  Why have the ability to customize your environment if everyone is forced to use the same settings?

Why doesn't TFS (or any other source control) remove unnecessary whitespace before committing a file based upon the file type?  This has several benefits.  One, the storage required to hold the file is less.  Two, the transmission of the file to the source control server should be more efficient since the file is smaller (these first two benefits are probably negligible since the files are probably compressed anyway).  Three, and most importantly, TFS (or any source control) will no longer report changes in whitespace when doing a file diff.

When I view/edit the file in my environment, it will be reformatted how I've defined it.  When someone else views/edits the file, it will be reformatted to their specification.

Is there a way to do this currently in TFS?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with source control. What about languages with syntactically significant whitespace, like Python? What about plaintext documents? What about markdown? 

You can't assume that whitespace is useless.

Comment: @el mojo, you are being difficult and trying to be the Hero Programmer that is the only one with the "correct way". If the entire team, bar you, want to use the default, then that is what you should do as well.

Comment: @MrHinsh  I'm not trying to be the "hero programmer" and I'm not saying my way is the "correct way".  I like my way better FOR ME.  I'm not asking everyone to adopt my way.  I happen to like two spaces instead of four for indentation.  Why can't the source control be smart enough to strip out unnecessary whitespace before committing?  Why have the ability to customize my formatting if we all have to use the same. You know why everyone prefers four spaces?  "Because that's the way it's always been."  That also happens to be the worst answer given for why something is done a certain way.

Comment: @ELMOJO This isn't a matter of source control. What you're talking about is IDE-specific behavior. You want your source control provider to be aware of different programming languages and know which ones are "safe" to strip whitespace from, then rely on the IDE to reformat it. That falls apart the second someone uses a different IDE (or no IDE at all) to work with the code. Also, for what it's worth, I find your rudeness to be extremely off-putting.

Comment: Agree with @daniel man. You need an IDE plugin that converts what you wants to look at to what everyone else wants. Not sure I have ever seen something like that..its a total corner case.. But you could check http://marketplace.visualstudio.com or build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Although what you said about is very reasonable, I still want to say the best solution is to get the entire team to use the same standards for white space in code. After all, you are teams.

If you insist on it, below is a workaround that to this problem (only works on your local machine).

In Visual Studio, select Tools / Options / Source Control / Visual Studio Team Foundation System and click the Configure User Tools button.

In the dialog, Add an item with the following settings.

- Extension : .*
- Operation : Compare
- Command   : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\diffmerge.exe
- Arguments : %1 %2 %6 %7 %5 /ignorespace

Depending on your **Visual Studio version** and **instalation path** (x64/x86), the command option may be...

**VS2010:** C:\Program Files *(x86)*\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\diffmerge.exe
**VS2012:** C:\Program Files *(x86)*\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\diffmerge.exe
**VS2013:** C:\Program Files *(x86)*\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe
**VS2015:** C:\Program Files *(x86)*\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe

In the argument option leave it with the same number of arguments as the VS suggests and just add /ignorespace in the end. For example, in the VS2015 it will be:

```
%1 %2 /ignorespace
```

More details you can refer this blog: [Configure Diff to Show Whitespace](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mitrik/2009/04/20/configure-diff-to-show-whitespace/)

You could also use another alternative. WinMerge is. It also has an option to ignore whitespace (menu Edit -> Options -> Compare -> Ignore all (under the groupbox "Whitespace" at the top)).

How to use WinMerge with TFS you can refer:

- [Using WinMerge with Team Foundation Server (TFS)](http://www.fruitbatscode.com/uncategorized/using-winmerge-with-team-foundation-server-tfs)
- [Using WinMerge as the default diff/merge tool in Visual Studio
  2012/2013](http://blog.degree.no/2013/12/using-winmerge-as-the-default-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-2012/)